# force:inputfield

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Following is my code:

**AccountFI.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="AccountController" implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Type}" class="elfForceEditable" />
</aura:component>
```

**AccountFIController.js**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, evt, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                component.set("v.account", a.getReturnValue());
                $('select.elfForceEditable').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class AccountController {
     @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount() {
        return [select Id, Name from Account Limit 1];
    }
}
```

I tried in dev org. I get an

> Internal Server Error, WARNING: Action failed: ltng$locker$controller$createComponent
>   aura_proddebug.js:14471 WARNING: Action failed: one$auraContainer$controller$init
>   aura_proddebug.js:14471 WARNING: components.createComponent(): client-side component creation failed
>   aura_proddebug.js:14471 WARNING: Event.setParams(): '0'('') is not a valid parameter. Valid parameters are 'componentDef', 'componentAttributes', 'forceServerDependencies', 'resetHistory', 'ignoreExistingAction'

Do we need to enable something for this component to work? Tried in Developer Pro sandbox as well, and still got the same error. I went through all the posts I could find, and it seems to work for everyone. I can't figure out why it does not work for me.

Comment: thank you Adrian!! for editing the post to make it readable.

Comment: Can you add Type field also to your SOQL and see if it helps

Comment: It didn't help adding Type in the SOQL. These are the warnings I received: WARNING: Action failed: ltng$locker$controller$createComponent
aura_proddebug.js:14471 WARNING: Action failed: one$auraContainer$controller$init
aura_proddebug.js:14471 WARNING: components.createComponent(): client-side component creation failed

Comment: Is that all code you have .I feel you have some events and thats causing issue..I would like to dig deeper if you could put all code here .

Comment: Yes Mohith, that is all the code I have. I am just trying out for a picklist in Lightning component. this is a trial. If this is success I want to use it in my code. And I have a lightning component tab for this component.

Comment: could you please add the same code on your end and see if it works. when I comment the code for Type( <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Type}" class="elfForceEditable" />) the name(<force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}"/>) is displayed and the code works.  It is not working for picklist.

Comment: Thanks ! If its as issue ,you will have to log a case with support and take from there

Comment: are force tags can only be used in Salesforce1?

Comment: That's correct.. In SF1 and lightning experience